# Twilio not working in Firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to use Twilio (for SMS) in a Firebase cloud function, however, when I add
`const twilio = require('twilio')` I get the error: *Functions did not deploy properly.* Without the require twilio the function is deployed successfully. I installed twilio with the command `npm install twilio` . Is there something I am missing? My project uses the blaze plan.

Here is the code:

```
const admin=require('firebase-admin');
const { firebaseConfig } = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp();
var db = admin.database();

const twilio = require('twilio');
//  const accountSid = functions.config().twilio.sid
//  const authToken  = functions.config().twilio.token
// const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);
// const twilioNumber = '' // your twilio phone number

exports.sendNotfication = functions.database.ref('payement/555')
   .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
     const original = snapshot.val();
     // client.messages
     // .create({
     //     from: twilioNumber,
     //     body: original,
     //     to: ''
     //   });
     const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
   });
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code so we can see if anything else is wrong ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj, I made an edit to the post. However, I think nothing else is wrong with the code, since it is deployed successfully if the line const twilio = require('twilio') is not included.

Comment: Did you add twilio to the dependencies in your `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Install the "twilio" package in the same folder as your Firebase "functions"
So navigate to the location(folder) where the firebase functions are,
Then do the 'npm install twilio'